# Face detection program displaying video in seperate windows

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection

I have been following this face detection course and we have recently implemented webcam. I have connected the webcam with the program but it is giving a window for every frame. And not putting it all together to make a video.
This is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import cv2
import face_recognition

webcam_video = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

all_face_locations = []

while True:
    ret,current_frame = webcam_video.read()
    current_frame_small = cv2.resize(current_frame, (0, 0),fx=0.25,fy=0.25)
    all_face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(current_frame_small,model='hog')
    for index,current_face_location in enumerate(all_face_locations):
        top_pos,right_pos,bottom_pos,left_pos = current_face_location
        top_pos = top_pos * 4
        right_pos = right_pos * 4
        bottom_pos = bottom_pos * 4
        left_pos = left_pos * 4
        print('found face {} at top:{},right:{},bottom:{},left:{}'.format(index+1,top_pos,right_pos,bottom_pos,left_pos))
        cv2.rectangle(current_frame,(left_pos,top_pos),(right_pos,bottom_pos),(0,255,0),2)
    cv2.imshow("Test",current_frame)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

webcam_video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I think this is because it is waiting at `cv2.waitKey(0)` and `cv2.destroyAllWindows()` but the program won't work without.

I tried deleting `cv2.waitKey(0)` and `cv2.destroyAllWindows()` but it didn't open any window